# Android API - Unable to run on devices set lower than target

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap, google-console-developer

I have a PhoneGap app which installs good on any version on Android using the APK.
But upon hosting on PlayStore as Internal Test, it doesn't allow it to be installed on device Android 8 or lower.

The error prompted is *"The device is not compatible with this version"*

On some other device not listed in Playstore, it just says Item Not Found.
I have choose all countries to host the app.

Following is the config file extract

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion"  value="23" />
<preference name="android-maxSdkVersion"  value="28" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion"  value="28" />
```

Please advice where I should I be looking into - Play store console or my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though not entirely sure where the problem was, but following config does work

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="23" />
<preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="29" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />
<preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
```

Set above in your config.xml file of your root folder.